# iOS 9.0, Xamarin Studio, "waiting for debugger to connect..."

Tags: xamarin

I have been using `Xamarin.iOS` platform with iPad with iOS 8.3 simulator successfully until I have updated Xcode 7 with iOS 9.0. When I select the simulator and run it, it keeps showing

> waiting for debugger to connect...

nothing comes out at the end. Any solution?

By the way, why I cannot able to see ios 8 simulator options in the Xamarin after I updated the Xcode?

Comment: Check your devices in xcode, after updating xcode it had to install a bunch of new stuff for the device I was using to debug.
EDIT: Woops I just now read that you're using a simulator, I did not do this so this is most likely not of help to you.

Comment: Have you tried launching XCode?  Often after an update it forces you to acknowledge a new EULA before it will allow you to use any features.

Comment: Hi Jason, yes I have been working on native app development as well. I used Xcode 7 with iOS9 simulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Was having the same issue.  Here is what helped me. Open up xcode go to Devices under Window menu. Select the simulator device you are trying to use. Right click and delete it.  Then add it again, bottom left + button. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have realized that there is no ios 8 simulator in the Xcode 7, it has been deleted. Now I am installing ios8 simulator. It will take sometime to download. Let me try afterwards. I have upvoted your answer as of now.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, follow these steps:

Open XCode and go to Locations options under the Preferences menu

> Xcode > Preferences > Locations

Check command line tools is selected. If not, select from the available list and close the window.

Try to debug the iOS app from Visual Studio again.

Comment: Reselecting the correct version of the Command Line tools from this dialog and then restarted VS fixed the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that but it is because of trash in debug/obj folders, I think. You can simply clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added a provisioning profile to you project.

Info.plist -> Signing -> Automatic Provisioning -> Select yours

I had the same problem and it was solved with this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone not using an emulator but using an iOS physical device, try updating your software on the device to the latest version. Give Visual Studio a restart, clean, and then build.

Comment: Do approach this with caution.  I updated the device, and found it was a newer version than my xcode + visual studio supported. I had to install a beta version of xcode to get support for the version of iOS the phone was now running.