# why am I not able to install iOS app to iPhone x simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, iphone-x, visual-studio-mac

[image]

> Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac Version 7.2.2 (build 11)
>   Installation UUID: 31d15ad0-e2b9-4dc5-bc31-0d1691b70a29 Runtime:  Mono
>   5.4.1.6 (2017-06/1f4613aa1ac) (64-bit)    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
>
> Package version: 504010006
>
> NuGet Version: 4.3.1.4445
>
> .NET Core Runtime: Not installed SDK: Not installed MSBuild SDKs:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks
>
> Xamarin.Profiler Version: 1.5.6 Location: /Applications/Xamarin
>   Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler
>
> Apple Developer Tools Xcode 9.1 (13532) Build 9B55
>
> Xamarin.iOS Version: 11.3.0.47 (Visual Studio Community) Hash:
>   51128b8c Branch: xcode9.1 Build date: 2017-10-31 22:42:13-0400

Any ideas why I am not able to install and how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you create an Xcode iOS project and debug it against a 11.1 simulator?

Comment: Xcode project works but not Xamarin.iOS

Comment: There's an old similar case, maybe you can have a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32978443/5474400

Comment: then why  would it work with Xcode project ?let me give a try anyway